# Force authentication for yahoo oauth

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, yahoo, yahoo-api

I am writing an application to fetch some information from Yahoo using OAuth. Now i want to force user to enter password even user has valid session on yahoo oauth page. How can i achieve this ?

Comment: No takers of this question?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, Yahoo doesn't have any option inside their OAuth flow to force the user to sign in or verify their password before they grant authentication a second time. However, I've experimented with this hack to force the user to sign out of their Yahoo account before starting the OAuth flow.

The trick is to render a hidden `iframe` with the Yahoo logout page:

```
<iframe src="https://login.yahoo.com/config/login?.src=fpctx&logout=1&.direct=1" style="display:none"></iframe>
```